# Trigonometric riddle. Obtaining Wind Speed based on two vectors of Ground Speed of an Airplane

Tags: trigonometry

[image]
The question:

> An airplane flies, and we know its ground speed and direction.  There is a wind of unknown speed and direction. The airplane changes its heading, so that we have a new ground speed and direction. The airplane speed with respect to air does not change.  Can we calculate the wind speed and direction based on this information?

What we have is:

Vector $C_1$: Ground Speed 1 and Direction 1, all known

Vector $C_2$: Ground Speed 2 and Direction 2, all known

Vector $A_1$: Air Speed (same)  Direction $B_1$ (unknown)

Vector $A_2$: Air Speed (same) Direction $B_2$ (unknown)

Vector $B_1$: Wind Speed and Direction (same)

Vector $B_2$: Wind Speed and Direction  (same)

This question has practical use for determining wind speed from UAVs. One easy way to measure wind speed is to make a $360$ degree circle and then obtain the wind speed which is half the difference between minimum and maximum ground speed. I wounder if it is possible to obtain the same result without doing a full circle, but just change course by a smaller angle ($60 - 90$ degrees) and use the changes in ground speed to determine the wind speed

I am not sure how to tackle it, but I feel that since we have the same airspeed, we probably could solve it...

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? How have you tried to solve it?

Comment: Make sure the UAV has a heading sensor and then you don't need it to turn at all.

Comment: If you don't know the UAV's heading at either time, there will typically be two solutions. In at least one of the solutions the wind speed is greater than the UAV's true airspeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply enable the measurement of heading (the direction of the airspeed vector) as well as ground course (the direction of the ground speed vector) then one measurement is enough to deduce the wind speed and direction.

If you insist that we know absolutely nothing about the heading of the aircraft when each ground speed measurement is taken, then we can at least draw the vector diagram a little differently (representing the exact same vector sum):

[image]

Knowing the magnitude and direction of each of the vectors $c_1$ and $c_2,$ as well as knowing the magnitude of $a_1$ (and that this is also the magnitude of $a_2$), 
we can determine the exact positions of the tips of the arrows for $c_1$ and $c_2,$
and then plot the common starting point of the vectors $a_1$ and $a_2.$
(That point will be on the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining the tips of
$c_1$ and $c_2$ at a suitable distance from both those points; an easy way to construct the vectors is to take half the vector difference $c_2 - c_1$ as one component, and use the Pythagorean theorem and the known length of the vectors $a_1$ and $a_2$ to compute the length of the component perpendicular to the first component.)

Once you have determined at least one of the vectors $a_1$ or $a_2$ in this way,
you can use a vector difference to find the wind vector $b.$

A weakness of this approach is that nothing in the solution so far tells us that the correct vector diagram is the one shown above rather than the one shown below.

[image]

Here we have the exact same direction and magnitude as before for each of the vectors $c_1$ and $c_2,$ and the same magnitude as before for each of the vectors $a_1$ and $a_2,$ but we get a very different wind vector.
And if you really know nothing about the heading of the aircraft, you have no way (other than guessing) which of these is the correct figure for the actual wind.

If you can distinguish a $90$-degree left turn from a $90$-degree right turn (and from a $270$-degree left turn), however, you can tell which of the two diagrams is correct.
(It's the first diagram for a left turn, the second for a right turn.)

Comment: The heading can be measured only with magnetic compass, and they are not very precise on the RC airplane

Comment: How precise is the magnitude and direction of the ground speed, I wonder? But you should be able to tell which way the turn was (and whether it was closer to 90 degrees or 270 degrees) either with the compass or by visual observation. Also, the second vector diagram will always say the wind is faster than the aircraft's airspeed, which you can usually rule out.

Comment: The find which solution is the correct one is very easy; in fact, there can be a third set of vectors. The basic (practical) idea is that the airplane changes course slightly to one side (by about 45 - 60 degrees max), then changes back to the other side, by  aprox, same amount, and then goes on previous course. This maneuver would be done by autopilot, and the computer can take any number of readings (Hroundspeed based

Comment: This maneuver would be done by autopilot which will keep the power and altitude fixed, and so the air speed would be the same, and the computer can take any number of readings (groundspeed based). The important part is that the left/roght turns are not excessive so as not to loose too much power.  A foolproof method is if during the turn you cross the wind direction, because then you would have airspeed and windspeed direction in one line; since GPS can be read every 0.2 seconds, one can pretty much get this point (when there is no change in ground speed, despite turning), or do a 360 turn.

Comment: With that maneuver there is no need to guess which vector diagram to apply. You would actually have more data than needed, and could use curve-fitting techniques to find the wind direction more accurately than would be possible with just one or two measurements.

Comment: The GPS is pretty precise (speed/course could be +- 1-2 % and 2°). Airspeed and magnetic headings can have a considerably higher error (5-10 % and 4 - 10°), airspeed as read (IAS) must be corrected for altitude, which is not difficult, to obtain TAS, but magnetic compass may have errors which would depend on power settings.

Comment: The most important point for me is to do no more than 45 left/right turn so as not to loose distance.  By the way, this whole thing is for a long range FPV Intelligent Autopilot system.The Autopilot would gather wind data on the outbound leg so as to calculate power required to come back.

Comment: But thanks for the answer...

Comment: If your GPS is that _accurate_ it is better than the one I use. (Mine is plenty _precise_ but it gives obviously wrong speeds between some readings.) But multiple measurements makes better accuracy. Anyway this technique certainly sounds possible. If you plot the ground speed vectors all from one point as in the figures above, then you just have to fit a circular arc close to all the arrow tips, and using the autopilot and estimated TAS you have a good idea how big an arc it is and which way it is oriented. The rest is details.

Comment: The best way to obtain accurate data from GPS is to take coordinate readings some 150 - 200 meters apart and about 10 seconds.  Usually, the absolute error would be in the range of 4-5 meters, and even then,the relative error would be much less. So I do believe that an accuracy of 2 % is achievable. I also checked the GPS speeds on ground in car, and they also seem to be pretty within that range.

Answer (score 0):

Buy an E6B flight computer.  It is a device created explicitly for this purpose.

If you want to learn the math.

Method 1, law of cosines / sin.

$C = A^2 + B^2 - 2AB\cos c$

In this case, $c$ the deviation between heading and course.

$A$ is you airspeed.  $B$ is your ground-speed.  $C$ will be the wind-speed.

law of sines

$\frac {\sin a}{A} = \frac {\sin b}{B} = \frac {\sin c}{C}$

$A,B, C, c$ are the same as above.

$a$ will be the difference between heading and the wind direction. 
$b$ will be the difference between ground-track and the wind direction.

Method 2 convert to Cartesian.

$\text{Heading} (v, \theta) = v\cos\theta, v\sin\theta\\
\text {Course} (s, \phi) = s\cos\phi, s\sin\phi\\
\text{wind}  = \text {Course - Heading} = s\cos\phi - v\cos\theta , s\sin\phi - s\sin\theta$

Wind speed $= \sqrt {(s\cos\phi - v\cos\theta)^2 + (s\sin\phi - s\sin\theta)^2}$

Wind direction $= \arctan \frac {s\sin\phi - s\sin\theta}{s\cos\phi - v\cos\theta}$

Wind direction is measured on a $0$ to $360$ scale, and $\arctan$ will return a number in $-90$ to $90$ so you will need to adjust, and you might find your indicated direction by the calculation to be $180$ degrees off.  So, you will need to run a sanity check to see if you have a headwind or a tailwind.

Comment: The computer assumes it will be told the aircraft's heading. OP has explicitly said the heading is unknown. That's an unnecessary and unrealistic constraint in my opinion, but possibly this question is not intended for practical application at all.

Comment: I can pretty much calculate one vector system (i.e.) ground speed/air speed/ wind, geometrically. The problem is exactly in the two sets of vectors. But David did a grwat job of explaining it, and I am now thinking how to implement it programatically